# How to improve WHERE NOT EXISTS from an INSERT statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to see if it's possible to improve the below query that is using a WHERE NOT EXISTS?

I want to add records from another table to a new one in batches of 500 where the key is in a temp table, it works but wanna improve its performance if possible.

```
WHILE 1 = 1 

BEGIN

INSERT INTO newTable WITH (TABLOCK)
        SELECT TOP(500) *
        FROM srcTable src
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM newTable WHERE pKey = src.pKey 
                          AND src.pKey IN (SELECT pKey FROM #TempTable))

IF @@ROWCOUNT < 500 BREAK
END
```

Thanks!

Comment: I would start by increasing the batch size. 500 rows is awfully small. I would think 10k would be around the tipping point of completing fast but not too many iterations.

Comment: How many rows you have in #TempTable?

Comment: #TempTable has 7072 records

Answer (score 0):

It seems strange to put both conditions in the `not exists`.  So I'm thinking:

```
INSERT INTO newTable WITH (TABLOCK)
    SELECT TOP(500) *
    FROM srcTable src
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM newTable nt WHERE nt.pKey = src.pKey) AND
          NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #TempTable tt WHERE src.pKey = t.pkey);
```

Then, for this query, I would want indexes on `newTable(pkey)` and `#TempTable(pkey)`.

Note:  I think I have that logic right.  Putting an `IN` to an unrelated table in a correlated `NOT EXISTS` is a little confusing.

EDIT:

Hmmm. . . If I got that logic wrong, then you just want `EXISTS` on the second condition:

```
INSERT INTO newTable WITH (TABLOCK)
    SELECT TOP(500) *
    FROM srcTable src
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM newTable nt WHERE nt.pKey = src.pKey) AND
          EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #TempTable tt WHERE src.pKey = t.pkey);
```

Comment: Would there be any conditions where it be more efficient to do an `inner join` between srcTable and #TempTable, as opposed to the `not exists` form?

Comment: @PhilipKelley . . . I cannot think of a way of replacing `not exists` with an `inner join`.  You can replace it with `left outer join`, and I'm guessing the performance would be comparable.  At least, either version (`left join` and `not exists`/`not in`) would be better than the current query because the first would optimize better.

Comment: The way I'm reading it, OP wants to copy over data from newTable only where ID is present in #temp table, and only if it hasn't been copied over yet. So, join newTable on #temp (only get legit targets), and then only copy if not already copied (as checked with `not exists`).

Comment: Definitely, original `where` clause is confusing!

Comment: Yes, Phillip, that is exactly what I'm trying to achieve